# Dividing a lumpy sequence into even parcels?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a "lumpy" sequence of items that I want to divide into a certain number of roughly equal-sized parcels while maintaining the sort order of the contents of the parcels (and the parcels themselves). Since nothing is new under the sun, I'm guessing I'm just lacking the proper name for the problem. My end goal is a python implementation of the algorithm, but I at least need a push in the right direction.

The problem is that I have a text, divided into sections of varying length, and I want to divide it up into a series of equitable readings. The ordering of the readings must, of course, remain the same.

For some specifics, I have 2,519 sections. The longest is 1,876 words, the shortest is 7 words. The average length is 305 words, and the median length is 242.

Comment: Do the readings always have to remain in section-order?

Comment: Yes, that's the requirement that makes this different from common bin-packing, I think.

Comment: What is an "equitable reading"?

Comment: The goal is to make all the readings roughly the same length. So, the closer to the mean/median, the better.

Comment: If the entire set of sections/readings must stay in order, you probably won't do better than computing `K = Total_Length / Number_Of_Readings`, and then just moving linearly through the text and stopping at each length-`K` chunk.

Comment: That easy, huh? I figured there was more to it than that. :)

Comment: @DavidEyk Unless you have some more requirements, no. You don't seem to have any bins or knapsacks in this.

Comment: But yes, you are right, the requirement of ordering makes this different from bin-packing. And that is that it's no longer a combinatorial problem, as you can't combine anything, since the order is fixed.

Comment: Entirely possible. I was thinking about bin-packing when this problem came up. I've removed the references to bins and knapsacks.

Comment: Also, EMS's algorithm doesn't really seem to work. It was vaguely defined, but here's what I think is a counter-example. Let the # of readings be 5, and here are the sections: 5 5 5 1 3 9. His algorithm I _believe_ outputs 5, 5, 5 1, 3, 9. A better split is 5, 5, 5, 1 3, 9

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if it exactly solves your program, but in the MIT OCW course [Introduction to Algorithms](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/lecture-videos/), they use [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) for solving the optimal splitting of lines so that the text is nicely filled out along a page ('[word-wrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_wrap#Algorithm)'), similar to what Latex does. See 17 minutes into [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=ENyox7kNKeY#t=17m05s).

This algorithm will give the guaranteed optimal splitting given some function that defines a penalty based on how ugly the line-splitting is. In the lecture, they define this uglyness function as `(pagewidth - actual_linewidth)^3`, but you could define your own function. The algorithm than more or less tries all the different splitting possibilities (in a smart way) and chooses the optimal one. The main requirement for DP is that the problem can be divided into sub-programs, e.g. that the solution for `n` words can be described based on previous solutions for `n-1, n-2, ...` words. These type of DP algorithms are typically `O(n^2)` or `O(n^3)`, so definitely not NP hard.

I highly recommend watching the whole lecture series if you are interested in basic algorithms, the teachers are great.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you an ok result, a "greedy" strategy:

- Figure out the average you are striving for, `avg = total_words / num_readings`.
- Start iterating through the sections, accumulating the count of words you have so far.
- If you hit an exact match, then mark that section and move on.
- Otherwise, if you're about to go over the word count, pick whether to include the next section or not based on what is closer to the avg, e.g. if you're 20 short if you don't include it but 100 over if you do, then leave it out.

To do better than that you need some heuristic. If you have messed up input, like one huge section and many smaller ones, say

```
100 100 100 100 100 100 40000 100 100 100 100
```

And you want to split it into 5 sections, what do you want your output to look like? My algorithm would give you this:

```
100 100 100 100 100 100
40000
100 100 100 100
0
0
```

You could easily adapt it to force at least one word per section:

```
100 100 100 100 100 100
40000
100 100
100
100
```

But then that might not be as "nice" as this option:

```
100 100 100
100 100 100
40000
100 100
100 100
```

Yes I recommend checking out the lecture that [Bas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19324872/15055) suggested. You have to adapt the heuristic a bit. For example, for you it's okay to have more words in one section, whereas for the line-packing, if you go over then it's infinitely bad.

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely looking for a "nice" solution, because the sections do differ quite a bit in size, and I expect a greedy approach would result in pathological results.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this piqued my curiosity so I wrote a dynamic programming algorithm with the simple badness heuristic of `abs(num_words - avg_words)**3`. It should work with any heuristic. Here are sample outputs:

```
>>> section_words = [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 40000, 100, 100, 100, 100]
>>> def heuristic(num_words, avg):
...     return abs(num_words - avg)**3
... 
>>> print_solution(solve(section_words, heuristic, 3))
Total=41000, 3 readings, avg=13666.67
Reading #1 (  600 words): [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
Reading #2 (40000 words): [40000]
Reading #3 (  400 words): [100, 100, 100, 100]
>>> print_solution(solve(section_words, heuristic, 5))
Total=41000, 5 readings, avg=8200.00
Reading #1 (  300 words): [100, 100, 100]
Reading #2 (  300 words): [100, 100, 100]
Reading #3 (40000 words): [40000]
Reading #4 (  200 words): [100, 100]
Reading #5 (  200 words): [100, 100]

>>> section_words = [7, 300, 242, 100, 115, 49, 563, 
                     1000, 400, 9, 14, 300, 200, 400, 
                     500, 200, 10, 19, 1876, 100, 200, 
                     15, 59, 299, 144, 85, 400, 600, 534, 200, 143, 15]
>>> print_solution(solve(section_words, heuristic, 10))
Total=9098, 10 readings, avg=909.80
Reading #1 (  649 words): [7, 300, 242, 100]
Reading #2 (  727 words): [115, 49, 563]
Reading #3 ( 1000 words): [1000]
Reading #4 (  723 words): [400, 9, 14, 300]
Reading #5 (  600 words): [200, 400]
Reading #6 (  729 words): [500, 200, 10, 19]
Reading #7 ( 1876 words): [1876]
Reading #8 (  902 words): [100, 200, 15, 59, 299, 144, 85]
Reading #9 ( 1000 words): [400, 600]
Reading #10 (  892 words): [534, 200, 143, 15]

>>> print_solution(solve(section_words, heuristic, 5))
Total=9098, 5 readings, avg=1819.60
Reading #1 ( 2376 words): [7, 300, 242, 100, 115, 49, 563, 1000]
Reading #2 ( 2023 words): [400, 9, 14, 300, 200, 400, 500, 200]
Reading #3 ( 1905 words): [10, 19, 1876]
Reading #4 ( 1302 words): [100, 200, 15, 59, 299, 144, 85, 400]
Reading #5 ( 1492 words): [600, 534, 200, 143, 15]

>>> print_solution(solve(section_words, heuristic, 3))
Total=9098, 3 readings, avg=3032.67
Reading #1 ( 3099 words): [7, 300, 242, 100, 115, 49, 563, 1000, 400, 9, 14, 300]
Reading #2 ( 3205 words): [200, 400, 500, 200, 10, 19, 1876]
Reading #3 ( 2794 words): [100, 200, 15, 59, 299, 144, 85, 400, 600, 534, 200, 143, 15]
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/HQvfRCDr)'s the code. Though I recommend trying to implement it yourself for a good exercise!

The sub-problem is `R(n, i, j)` which is: what is the lowest badness for splitting sections `i` through `j` with `n` readings?

Base case is simple:

```
R(1, i, j) = heuristic(num words in sections i thru j, total words / total sections)
```

Then for the recursion you find the best solution out of all the possible ways to split the number of sections you have left among the left & the right, and the best place to put that partition:

```
R(n, i, j) = the lowest badness out of
    R(1, i, i+1) + R(n-1, i+1, j)
    R(1, i, i+2) + R(n-1, i+2, j)
    ...
    R(1, i, j-1) + R(n-1, j-1, j)

    R(2, i, i+1) + R(n-2, i+1, j)
    R(2, i, i+2) + R(n-2, i+2, j)
    ...
    R(2, i, j-1) + R(n-2, j-1, j)

    ...
    ...

    R(n-1, i, i+1) + R(1, i+1, j)
    R(n-1, i, i+2) + R(1, i+2, j)
    ...
    R(n-1, i, j-1) + R(1, j-1, j)
```

Pathological case is when you have more readings than sections:

```
R(n, i, j) = infinity if n > j-i
```

You build up the solution going from `n=1` and up, then from `j-i = 1` and up, then from `i=0` and up.

It ends up having 5 nested for-loops so I'm not sure if it's as efficient as it can be, but it seems to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! This will be a big help in comprehending the text justification video. I'll implement itself, too, to handle the specifics of my situation.